# Comment/uncomment a line where a word is matched without using sed/awk

Tags: bash, comments

How can I comment out lines where a certain word can be found in a bash script, using piped UNIX commands (no sed/awk) ?

The comment character is `#` .

Here is how It could start :

```
cat $file | grep $word |  ...
```

Comment: I suggest to start [there](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: Please clarify your question by editing the extra information into the question, then removing the comment, and you can then flag this comment as obsolete.  Why aren't `sed` and `awk` usable on your system?  Wouldn't it be simpler to make them usable?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It would, but then this question would be pointless. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU bash.

```
#!/bin/bash

keyword="foo"

while IFS= read -r line; do
  [[ "$line" =~ $keyword ]] && line="${line#*#}"
  printf "%s\n" "$line"
done < /etc/network/interfaces > /tmp/interfaces_modified
```